# Adding Library to SBT Test File

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm having problems running a `scalatest` from SBT.

```
> test
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to C:\side-work\MonadsSbt\target\scala-2.10
\test-classes...
[error] C:\side-work\MonadsSbt\src\test\scala\tests\TestMonadLaws.scala:4: 
object scalatest is not a member of package org
[error] import org.scalatest._
```

Here's part of my `project/build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"

resolvers +=  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at 
"https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

Comment: Do you happen to have an object `org` in the same scope as your `TestMonadLaws`? What happens if you import `_root_.org.scalatest._`?

Comment: There's no object `org` in the same scope as my `TestMonadLaws`. I tried your import, and then ran `sbt test`, but got `object scalatest is not a member of package org`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be either `build.sbt` or `project/Build.scala`, not `project/build.sbt`. The latter would be a build file for a build file - a "meta-build file".

Comment: That worked, thanks. I had originally moved my `build.sbt` to this **bad** location, but then moved it based on this comment - https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/177#issuecomment-28498781. After your change, I can run my tests, but I [unreleated] can't run `gen-idea` to make an IntelliJ project.

Comment: Wow! No wonder people say Scala is baffling! I've never seen that before. But I don't use IntelliJ so I can't help you there.